# why mod_auth_kerb won't work when not joined to domain?

Tags: apache, active-directory, kerberos, samba

I'm trying to set up Active Directory Kerberos authentication with apache, using [these](http://acksyn.org/?p=460) instructions.

I would like apache to be able to authenticate users against AD without the apache machine being joined to the domain via Samba. My understanding of Kerberos is that there should be no need for my apache server to join the domain (I thought the above instructions only did it so that they could generate the keytab easily).

But in fact it will not work if I have the apache host leave the domain. It works fine as long as it stays joined. When I leave, and try to hit my secured URL, I get challenged for credentials, but the credentials I enter are not accepted. Here's what comes up in the apache log in that case:

```
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:38 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 192.168.201.52] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:43 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 192.168.201.52] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:43 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1031): [client 192.168.201.52] Using HTTP/centosjb.iga.local@ABC.LOCAL as server principal for password verification
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:43 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(735): [client 192.168.201.52] Trying to get TGT for user myuser@ABC.LOCAL
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:44 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(645): [client 192.168.201.52] Trying to verify authenticity of KDC using principal HTTP/centosjb.iga.local@ABC.LOCAL
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:44 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(660): [client 192.168.201.52] krb5_get_credentials() failed when verifying KDC
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:44 2013] [error] [client 192.168.201.52] failed to verify krb5 credentials: Server not found in Kerberos database
[Wed Mar 27 12:33:44 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1110): [client 192.168.201.52] kerb_authenticate_user_krb5pwd ret=401 user=(NULL) authtype=(NULL)
```

Here is my krb5.conf file (I left out the log file part):

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = ABC.LOCAL
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 ABC.LOCAL = {
  kdc = labdc12.abc.local
  admin_server = labdc12.abc.local
 }

[domain_realm]
 .abc.local = ABC.LOCAL
 abc.local = ABC.LOCAL
```

I had a feeling it might be something as simple as a DNS issue, based on the 'server not found' message...i.e. there is something my apache host can only resolve when it's joined to the domain. But testing with ping all names resolve just fine. Can anyone explain why this will not work?

Answer (score 2):

The SPN for this host are removed with the removal of the machine account (Server not found in Kerberos database). The best way is to do:

```
$ net ads join
$ net ads keytab add HTTP
```

Wait for that to replicate across all DCs and your problem should go away.

In other words: unless there is no SPN registered for that machine account you will fail with the message above. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463166.aspx) for error 0x7.

Comment: Thanks! Since I posted this I got it working another way. I got the AD admin to generate the keytab a different way - by running KTPASS on the Windows machine, as described here: http://www.grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/

Once I started using that keytab, everything worked perfectly without the Apache server needing to join the domain at all.